# Best message to display when migrating data?

Tags: progress-bar, loading

The use case is this: users who downloaded a new version of an app will need to go through a data migration process after log in (which may last up to 1 minute) during which user data from an old server will be migrated to a new one.

For this purpose, I'd like to display a loading screen with an animated progress indicator and an appropriate message which will explain briefly what's happening in the background. What would be the best message to display?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please wait while we copy your data to the new app.

This may take a few minutes.

---

- use simple language
- make sure they wait just in case they do something that could jeopardise the transfer (e.g. turn off data or device)
- don't confuse them by mentioning the server migration
- leave them pleased when it takes less than 'a few minutes'